# Maximize the linear function $L(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)=\sum^n_1C_jx_j$

Tags: calculus

Let $C_1\geq C_2\geq\dots\geq C_n$ be a fixed set of positive numbers. Maximize the linear function $L(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)=\sum^n_1C_jx_j$ in the closed set described by the inequalities $0\leq x_j\leq 1, \sum^n_1 x_j\leq A$
I think this question can be solved by simplex method, but it happens in a calculus book, so can I solve it using some pure calculus method? I tried to find the critical points, but it equals $[c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n]$, and can not equal $0$.

Comment: you don't need simplex for it. Can you solve it for $n=2$? What happen if $A < 1$, or $=1$, or $> 1$?

Comment: @user251257 Yes, thanks, should be $0 \le x_j \le 1$

Comment: If there are no critical points, it's sufficent to consider values on the boundary only, namely the vertices of that given polytope (as the objective function can increase along edges or faces). @Cathy

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I know it's true in $R$, but I haven't learnt a theorem showing it's also true in $R^n$ yet, is there a particular theorem prove it?

Comment: For LPs, the solution is characterized by the complementary slackness conditions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_programming  You can use a "calculus approach" by way of Kuhn Tucker: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C_1 > C_2 > ... C_k > 0$ be the subset of $C_k$'s that are strictly positive.

Set 
$$
x_1 = \min \{ 1, A\}.
$$

If $x_1 < A$, set 
$$
x_2 = \min \{ 1, A - 1 \}
$$

If we reach the $j$-th $x_j$ and $(j-1) < A$, set
$$
x_j = \min \{1, A - (j-1) \}
$$

And so on, until the $A$ constraint binds or you run out of strictly positive $C_k$ coefficients.

No, uh, calculus required.  I don't think, unless I read the problem wrong.

Comment: May we see the proof or some reasoning of such choice of $x_j$ makes the maximum value of the obrective function?

Comment: The $C_k$'s decrease monotonically in $k$. The gradient is just $(C_1,...,C_N)$. The greatest gain in the objective is from increasing the $x_k$ with the smallest index. Do so until one of the constraints binds, then move to the next $x_k$ with the next largest coefficient.

Comment: Or, do it by contrapositive: suppose the solution was such that $x_{k+\ell}$ had more and strictly positive weight on it than $x_k$. I can improve the value of the objective by moving weight from $x_{k+\ell}$ to $x_k$. But that means if the lower-index terms are not set to 1 or the $A$ constraint is not binding or both, I can improve the value of the objective. That means the proposed solution is not optimal, so it must satisfy the conditions given above.

Comment: I think both reasonings are enough rigorous. Please consider an option of including them into the answer, as they are not so obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the feasible set by 
$$ S = \Bigl\{ x \in [0,1]^n \mid \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \le A \Bigr\}. $$ 
If $A < 0$, we have $S=\emptyset$ and there is no maximum (or $-\infty$ depending on convention). 
If $A = 0$ the unique maximizer is the zero-vector $0$.
**So let us assume $A > 0$ from now on.**

Assume $A = m + r$ where $m\in\mathbb N$ (including $0$) and $r\in [0, 1)$.
Then, for any $x\in S$ we have
$$ L(x) = C_1 x_1 + C_2 x_2 + \dotsb + C_n x_n \le C_1 + C_2 + \dotsb + C_m + C_{m+1} r. $$

**Proof:**
Fix any $x\in S$ with $x_j < 1$, $x_{k} > 0$, and $j < k$. Then for any $0 < \varepsilon \le \min(1 - x_j, x_k)$ the point $\tilde x$ with 
$$ \tilde x_i = \begin{cases}
x_i, & i \ne j, i \ne k, \\
x_j + \varepsilon, & i = j, \\
x_k - \varepsilon, & i = k
\end{cases} $$
is in $S$ again and we have
$$ L(x) \le L(\tilde x). $$

**Notice:** In case of $m = n$ or $C_m > C_{m+1}$ there is exactly one maximizer. In case of $C_m = C_{m+1}$ the maximizer is not unique. For example 
$$ x = (\underbrace{1,\dotsc, 1}_{m-1}, 1, r, 0, \dotsc, 0) $$ 
and 
$$ \hat x = (\underbrace{1,\dotsc, 1}_{m-1}, r, 1, 0, \dotsc, 0) $$
are two maximizers.